# Pandas interpolate: slinear vs index

Tags: pandas, interpolation

In Pandas [interpolate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) what is the difference between using `method` of `slinear` vs `index`?

Comment: slinear is first order spline linear interpolation

Answer (score 3):

method='slinear' will only interpolate "inside" values.  It will not interpolate None values that do not have a valid value on both sides.

Using index values will default to limit_direction='forward' which will interpolate inside values and anything after a non NaN value.

Notice in the other posted example, if you set v to None where either t is 100 or where t is 11 (both ends of the sorted index), the result will not be interpolated when using method='slinear'.  This is VERY useful for interpolating values inside a series, when you don't want to extending the series.

Thanks to  @TomAugspurger on GitHub for explaining this.

Comment: Mind linking to the GH conversation?

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16284#issuecomment-299878944